# Unstable bluetooth connection on Windows IoT Core - even using an external dongle

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-iot-core

I am using my RaspberryPis (v3) running the latest stable Windows IoT Core version (v.10.0.17763.737) to retrieve data and control my bluetooth thermostats. I am struggling quite a long time with the stability of the bluetooth connection. Some months ago I switched all my nodes to external dongles (one from the microsoft compatibility list: ORICO BTA-403), which improved the situation, but it is still far away from being stable.

After a certain time (varies from minutes to days) the bluetooth connection stops working. I already implemented a powershell script to check for such situations and fire a "devcon restart *USB*" command. This helps, but only in about 50% of all failures. If it does not solve the situation, I have to reboot the node. However, this is not satisfying, because from time to time the nodes freeze while booting and I made the experience that doing too many reboots will reduce the lifetime of the micro sd card.

After some hours of analysis I found out that the bluetooth support service could be the problem. Before the connection crashes I can easily restart the bluetooth support service using powershell. After the problem occured, this is not possible anymore. The service restart hangs up and the status of the service says it is pending for restart or something like this.

Do you guys made the same experience? Or is my bluetooth connection implementation too bad? I attached the function for you to have a look:

```
private async Task Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count++;
                if (count > 10)
                {
                    m_IsInitialized = false;
                    //throw new Exception("More than 10 tries have not been successfull for connecting with thermostat module. Stopping.");
                }
                m_IsInitialized = false;

                m_Device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(m_DeviceID);
                if (m_Device == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Device was not found.");
                }

                m_Characteristics = new Dictionary<ushort, GattCharacteristic>();
                GattDeviceServicesResult gattServices = await m_Device.GetGattServicesAsync();
                foreach (GattDeviceService service in gattServices.Services)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        GattCharacteristicsResult characteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                        IReadOnlyList<GattCharacteristic> characteristics = characteristicsResult.Characteristics;
                        foreach (GattCharacteristic characteristic in characteristics)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                m_Characteristics.Add(characteristic.AttributeHandle, characteristic);
                                GattCharacteristicProperties properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;
                                if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        GattCommunicationStatus status = await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
                                        if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                        {
                                            characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;
                                            m_IsInitialized = true;
                                            //Logger.ServiceLog(string.Format("Thermostat has been initialized successfully ({0} tries).", count));
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex4)
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception("4: GattCommunicationStatus: " + ex4.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex4.StackTrace);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex3)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("3: GattCharacteristic: " + ex3.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex3.StackTrace);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("2: GattDeviceService: " + ex2.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex2.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
                //Logger.ServiceLog(string.Format("Thermostat:Connect: Unsuccessful try: {0}", count));
                await Task.Delay(1 * 60 * 1000);
            }
            while (!m_IsInitialized);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.ServiceLog("1: Thermostat.cs Connect", ex);
        }
    }
```

As you see, the code is full of debugging helps, **but no exception is raised at all when the connectivity collapses**. I am really looking forward to any help, because after months of struggling I would really prefer getting to a stable solution without any hacks or workarounds.

Thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: 1) uwp 2) stability, pick one!

Comment: I understand your point, Mehrzad, but i think it must be possible somehow. I think I identified the problem down to the bluetooth control service (bthserv), but I have no clue how to get it back running or successfully restart it without rebooting the whole node...

Comment: Problem is not in service. Bluetooth Framework runs on RPi without any problem days and days (however it does not support UWP and runs as console app).

Comment: Did you also use C# for your application, Mike? Is it a bluetooth low energy device? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Please refer to my response in MSDN forum(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53463606-4354-417b-9395-2c3ab56d6f51/unstable-bluetooth-connection-even-using-external-dongle?forum=WindowsIoT).